# Django site: Where to store SQL setup commands?

Tags: django

I am working in Django 1.8 with a Postgres database.

My site contains a large dataset and I want to create some extra Postgres indices to speed up certain queries (above and beyond what you can do with `db_index` in the models file). I also need to create some materialised views.

I have SQL commands to do this, in a psql script.

My question is where to store these SQL commands so they're easy to run as part of the overall site setup (I want to make it easy to deploy and initialise the site).

Right now I just have a README saying "don't forget to run setup.psql after creating your database!!!" which isn't ideal.

When reading [this article](http://dlo.me/archives/2014/09/01/postgresql-fts/#south), I spotted that the author suggests putting index creation commands into a migration file, so they're run as as part of the initial `python manage.py migrate` to set up the database.

Is this sensible? Are there any drawbacks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is sensible, this is how I do it.

I don't see any drawbacks except maybe (since this is an existing project as I understand) if you run the new migration on a database which already has the indexes and views, this might crash your migration, so make sure to catch the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [a post migrate signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_migrate) to run your commands. I never used it but I used [post syncdb signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#post-syncdb) in a previous project but it's deprecated now. In my case there where no drawbacks.